# Arguments too long exception to delete 10k files-Python -HDFS

Tags: python, hdfs, delete-file

I have 15k files with different dates in HDFS folder. I am trying to delete the files older than 10 days in which I have 10k files to be deleted from HDFS. When I was trying to delete these 10k files at a time by passing to a list I'm getting error. Could you please help me in sorting this issue.
I tried to use find and xargs but it is accepting single file but not multiple fils.

```
delete_cmd = 'hadoop fs -find /test/folder/* -name ' +filepath+ ' | xargs hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash'
```

OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'

```
folder = '/test/folder/*'
no_of_days = 10
now_dt = datetime.now()

def list_files():
  hdfs_cmd = "hdfs dfs -ls -r " + folder  + " | grep / " 
  hdfs_output = subprocess.getoutput(hdfs_cmd)
  return hdfs_output

def delete_cmd(filepath):
  delete_cmd = 'hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash '  + filepath 
  delete_output = subprocess.getoutput(delete_cmd)
  print(delete_output)

def delete_olderfiles():
  hdfs_outputfun = list_files()
  delete_list = []
  filepath_list = [line.split(' ')[-1] for line in hdfs_outputfun.splitlines()]
  for filepath in filepath_list:
        filename = filepath.split('/')[-1]
        filename_dt = datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y%m%d.csv')
    diff_days = (now_dt - filename_dt).days
    if diff_days > no_of_days:
        delete_list.append(filepath)
 string = " " 
 delete_folders = string.join(delete_list)
 delete_cmd(delete_folders)

delete_olderfiles()
```

output to delete files:
hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash file20210901.csv file20210801.csv file20210903.csv ...10kfiles

Comment: If you're obtaining all the filenames in that script, I would just write them to a file and run the command ```'cat filelist | xargs hadoop ....'```. ```find``` isn't adding anything to the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the command line can only take so much data as arguments as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command

> On Linux, the maximum amount of space for command arguments is 1/4th of the amount of available stack space. So, a solution is to increase the amount of space available for the stack.

Short version: run something like

```
ulimit -s 65536
```

Another solution would be to call the rm command once per file:

```
for item in delete_list:
    delete_cmd(item)
```

and put this code at the end of your `delete_olderfiles()` (and do not call `delete_cmd()` on a contcatinated list of all the files to delete).

Comment: I used rm to delete once per file but it is taking a lot of time(5 hours) to delete all the 10k files so I had to change the approach to delete all the files at a time.

Comment: That isn't to do with running the command one at a time and more to do with the size of the files. Also, don't `print()` every time you run the `rm` command. What approach did you use?

Comment: I wanted to check what files are being deleted so I have given Print() while deleting the files.
If I use for loop It is running rm command everytime for each file (10k files-10k time) and taking a lot of time to delete the files
So I'm trying to pass all the files at a time to the command like below
`hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash file20210901.csv file20210801.csv file20210903.csv`